# e^x^e^x ? Ways to reduce problem in an equation?

Tags: exponential-function, associativity

Why, when solving this problem in an equation we *have* to associate or disassociate the e^x as a unit because when we solve and separate out the x^e or even x^(e^x) as a unit the answer is different and wrong.  Why does this happen?  If this is understood as ((e^​x^​)^(e^​x)) the answer is correct because this does not equal e^(​(x^​e)^​x).  Is there another *layer* of order of operations involved here for the term e^x?

Background: I was told this in high school while I was learning calculus to just accept this but it never made sense?  I was told that e^x has to stay together and it is the way it is because we do it that way.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{x^{e^x}}$ or something else ?  There are many ways to read **e^x^e^x**

Comment: Powers of powers multiplies powers, $e^{x^{e^x}}=e^{ex^2}$. There is no necessity to keep $e^x$ together.

Comment: @Cocomos. I do not think that this is correct $f(x)=e^{x^{e^x}}-e^{e^{x^2}}$ Make $x=1$ and  check the number.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It appears I did my order of operations all backwards-like. I retract my previous statement. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: The answer below is good in that it tells you why exponentiation is usually defined to be right-associative, but it should be stressed that operator precedence and associativity are *conventions* (although some conventions are so common that they're 'facts', like precedence of multiplication over addition). One could even require that everything have enough parentheses to be fully unambiguous and then no such rules would be needed, but that gets ugly. Conventions aren't always uniform: the first prompt I opened to check this was Octave, which happens to have left-associative exponentiation.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen : I note that [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html) for the power operator claims "The implementation of this operator needs to be improved."  Octave of course agrees with MatLab (for which all arithmetic operators of equal precedence [are evaluated left-to-right](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html), except for the six that are evaluated second from the right to left).

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\mathrm{e}\text{^}x\text{^}\mathrm{e}\text{^}x = \mathrm{e}\text{^}(x\text{^}(\mathrm{e}\text{^}x)) = \mathrm{e}^{x^{\mathrm{e}^x}}   \text{.}$$  Exponentiation is [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity): in the form $a\text{^}b\text{^c}$ the right-most exponent "binds more tightly", so must be evaluated first.  This applies recursively, so in a chain of exponents, we parenthesize as written above.

(Aside: $$(\mathrm{e}\text{^}x)\text{^}(\mathrm{e}\text{^}x) = \left( \mathrm{e}^x \right)^{\mathrm{e}^x}$$ is neither left nor right associative.  It is not the rule used for evaluating exponentials.)

Notice that pretending that exponentiation were left-associative would produce different results.  \begin{align*}
    (2\text{^}3)\text{^}4 &= (8)\text{^}4 = 4096  \text{ and} \\
    2\text{^}(3\text{^}4) &= 2\text{^}81 = 2\,417\,851\,639\,229\,258\,349\,412\,352  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Another way to write this is
$$ (2^3)^4 = 2^{3 \cdot 4} = 2^{12} = 4096.$$
That is, if we pretend that exponentiation is left-associative, we must end up multiplying all the exponents together, instead of exponentiating them.  And then there's no reason to use the stacked notation "$\mathrm{e}^{x^{\mathrm{e}^x}}$" if we just wanted $\mathrm{e}^{x \cdot \mathrm{e} \cdot x}$  So in order that a repeated exponential not be "just ordinary multiplication of the exponents", exponentiation *has* to be right associative.

Comment: With such a last name, I suppose that you enjoyed the problem (easy joke for sure) ! Cheers.

Comment: The answer for e^x^e^x does not follow the right to left rule for towers of powers.  The answer is different for this type of grouping compared to right to left.  I used it in calculus to find the area under this curve from say 0 to 1 and solving via trapezoids gives the close estimation to the e^x grouping not the right to left rule used for evaluating exponentials.  It is the physics of this difference is what I am interested in?   You are correct with the basic idea but found this is an interesting twist to the forms.

Comment: @BillNewbold : You say "The answer" ...  The answer to what?  There is no question here nor in the original post.  The convention for unparenthesised exponential towers is right-associative.  5^4^3^2 ${}= 5^{4^{3^2}} = 5^{4^9} = 5^{262144} \approx 6.2\times 10^{183230}$.  $\left. \mathrm{e}^{x^{\mathrm{e}^x}} \right|_{x = 3} \approx 2.4 \times 10^{1663492663}$.  You say you used calculus to find an area, but show no calculation and no result, so you provide no context and no definite statement with which to agree or disagree.